# What is the probability that 0 appears as a digit for a total of 3 times in a randomly selected 9-digit number?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Considering 9-digit numbers where each digit is one of the 10 integers 0, 1, ⋯ , 9.

The answer given for the question was 8C3 * (9C1)^6 / (10C1)^8 * 9C1

However, i dont quite understand where 8C3 came from.

I did (9C1)^6 / (10C1)^8 * 9C1 because i felt that the 3 zeros should be fixed (ie (1C1)^3)

Can i understand how 8C3 came about?

Also i'm having issues putting combinatorics with power signs even after googling. How do u combine combinatorics with power signs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first digit of the number cannot be $0$, so there are only $8$ possible places for the three zeroes, and there are $\binom83$ ways to choose $3$ of those places. Once those $3$ places have been filled with zeroes, each of the remaining $6$ places can have any of the $9$ non-zero digits, so there are $9^6$ ways to fill those places, for a total of $\binom83\cdot9^6$ different $9$-digit numbers having exactly $3$ zeroes.

Comment: Why is it that we cannot fill the 6 places first with (9C1)^6, then fill the remaining slots with zeros with (1C1)^3? 1C1 because the slots can only take one value, which is zero

Comment: @Desmond: That calculation would be correct if the $3$ zeroes were required to be in $3$ specific places, for instance the last $3$. It doen’t take into account the fact that the $3$ zeroes can appear in **any** set of $3$ places. If you want to deal with the other $6$ digits first, you can, but it’s a little more complicated. You know that one of them has to go in the first slot, but the other $5$ can occupy any of the last $8$ positions, so there are actually $\binom85$ ways to choose positions for the non-zero digits. Then you can multiply that by $9^6$.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you

Comment: @Desmond: You’re welcome.